# Xamarin TouchRunner Hangs calling IOS 3rd Party Binding

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, nunit

I have a 3rd party API IOS Binding which I am trying to test (more like an integration test) using `TouchRunner`.

An example API Method is this -

```
 _client.AuthenticateWithUsername(username, token,
    () => { // Success Callback },
    () => { // NoConnection Callback },
    (obj) => { // Other Error Callback });
```

The API when called goes off and does some work in the background then eventually makes one of the callbacks above, I would like to control the flow of the unit test using something like -

[How can I unit test async methods on the UI Thread with Xamarin iOS TouchRunner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25676672/how-can-i-unit-test-async-methods-on-the-ui-thread-with-xamarin-ios-touchrunner)

Unfortunately, when I insert the `AutoResetEvent` code, `TouchRunner` just hangs and never returns to the GUI.

I have also tried to use a `TaskCompletionSource` as follows -

```
    public async Task<AuthResponse> AuthenticateUserAsync(string username, string password)
    {
        TaskCompletionSource<AuthResponse> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<AuthResponse>();

        AuthResponse response = new AuthResponse { Success = false };

        LoginResponse loginResponse = await LoginUser(username, password);

        _client.AuthenticateWithUsername(username, loginResponse.token,
             () =>
               {
                   response.Success = true;
                   Console.WriteLine("Auth");
                   tcs.SetResult(response);
               },
               () => { tcs.SetResult(response); },
               obj => { tcs.SetResult(response); },
               obj => { tcs.SetResult(response); });

        return await tcs.Task;
    }

    [Test]
    public async void AuthenticateUserAsyncTest()
    {
        var auth = await AuthenticateUserAsync(_username, _password);

        Assert.IsTrue(auth.Success);
    }
```

The debugger stepped through fine until the return await `tcs.Task`, but then results in a similar HUNG runner.

How can I work out why the hang is happening?

As this was not working, I then resorted to code like this -

```
 _client.AuthenticateWithUsername(_username, loginResponse.token,
     () =>
     {
         Assert.Pass("This crashes the runner");
         Assert.True(true);  // This DOES NOT!
     },
     () =>
     {
         // This will crash runner also
         Assert.Fail("NoConnection");
     },
     (InvalidTokenError obj) =>
     {
         Assert.Fail("InvalidToken" + obj.Description);
     },
     (ClientError obj) =>
     {
         Assert.Fail("ClientError" + obj.Description);
     });
```

As you can see, the flow ends up (understandably), run test, runs client call, end of test method completes which shows test as success, then the callback returns and the asserts get called, which crash the app, which we assume is because the runner has already completed the test, why one assert works and other crashes I do not know.

So,

- Am I approaching this the right way?
- Could something be happening in the 3rd Party API that will cause these approaches to hang? and how would I debug that?

Comment: One observation is that the test should be `async Task` and not `async void` ie `public async Task AuthenticateUserAsyncTest()`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Nkosi, that is a good suggestion, I forgot to add that during my original testing that when I ran the code with async Task rather than void I got an immediate block from TouchRunner without even adding any other code other than the API call! This was a red flag I suppose, but using async void "seemed" to allow "standard" async testing, so I progressed and then ended up in the loop above.

As TouchRunner has not been updated in a very long time I have just spent time re-creating the test project using XUnit after various suggestions to try it in the forums and on stack.

- https://github.com/xunit/devices.xunit - runners for Xamarin IOS + Android
- https://xunit.github.io/docs/comparisons - to port NUnit syntax

Some other useful links are -

- https://xunit.github.io/docs/getting-started-devices.html
- https://gregshackles.com/testing-xamarin-apps-getting-started-with-xunit/
- https://oren.codes/2014/07/10/getting-started-with-xunit-for-xamarin/

**RESULT: I am very pleased to say all the above code now works for both the TaskCompletionSource and the AutoResetTask scenarios**

I can now safely test my event based API :)

I just wanted to ensure other users are aware of this.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

One observation is that the test should be `async Task` and not `async void` ie

```
public async Task AuthenticateUserAsyncTest() {
    //...code removed for brevity.
}
```

async void is a fire and forget so any exceptions thrown wont happen in the current context so they wont be caught.

Reference [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)